# System ui tuner not enabling in lenovo a6600

Tags: lenovo-a660

I cant turn on the system ui tuner on my lenovo A6600 no mater what i do. The system gear spins on long press but nothing happens. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Maybe lenovo disabled it? Not particularly hard to do.

Answer (score 0):

There's an alternative app on [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zacharee1.systemuituner) that works the same as, if not better than, the inbuilt System UI Tuner.